# Div not resizing properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to set a divs height equal to a calculation of its parent div. This is the code I have:

```
var cw = ($(".portfoliocontainer").width()/4)

alert(cw);

$('.portfoliopod').css({'height':cw+'px'});
```

I have the parent div set as calc(100%-300px). The alert is giving me the dimensions I want in pixels. However when it applies the height to the class portfoliopod its spitting out the percentage value (25%) as the value therefore the height becomes 25px.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds impossible, seeing as `cw` has the correct value and even the string `px` is added.

Comment: live example http://mrliger.com/index2.php (click on portfolio)

Comment: Seems just fine, the inline style tag shows the `.portfoliopod` elements having a pixel value

Comment: Oh wait, that was because I resized the browser window. You did something wrong somewhere didn't you

Comment: Maybe the window resize callback (or some other function that also sets the height) is getting called immediately after that code.

Comment: yea the resize function works which is strange. Its just the initial load. Also when you resize the browser window its not quite perfect. The height calculation does not go to 3 decimal places. Any way of fixing this?

Comment: no there is no other function that resizes it

Comment: somebody help please!

Comment: @BenLiger Do you think you could post a minimal example of the problem. I'm finding it hard to debug your JS file.

Comment: BTW, I think you can replace some of your window resize code with CSS3 animations and media queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are triggering a resize event on the window. This causes your window resize callback to fire, which in turn sets `.portfoliopod` height to `25px`. Here is the problematic code:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    $('.portfoliopod').each(function() {
        $(this).height($(this).width());
    });
}).resize();
```

`$(this).width()` is `25px` to start out with.

**Edit**
I think this is what you want:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var cw = $(".portfoliocontainer").width()/4;
    $('.portfoliopod').height(cw);
});
```

Comment: ok im still a bit confused though. what would be the solution?

Comment: I guess what im trying to achieve is have the width of the div always at 25% and have the height the same, but in pixels. If there is an easier way to do that with css or different javascript then that is suitable too

Comment: One more thing, when I click on the pod itself the height stays the same (as it should) but I want the height of the pod to expand so the whole image is visible. Any quick way to do this?

Comment: Depends really; you could have a function toggle a CSS class when the pod is clicked, and the CSS class overrides the default height/width

Comment: Ive tried that but because the height is displayed in-line it doesnt overwrite the height properly. Ideally id likr to have height auto i guess as the expanded height

Comment: Have you tried using `!imporant`? You should probably open a new question if need additional help.